# Html.Encode() doesn't encode a space

Tags: asp.net-mvc, encoding

In my asp.net-mvc website I have a field that usually has a string (from database) but can from time to time contain nothing.
Because IE doesn't know how to handle the css "empty-cells" tag, empty table cells need to be filled with an &nbsp;
I thought

```
Html.Encode(" ");
```

would fix this for me, but apparantly, it just returns " ".
I could implement this logic as follows

```
Html.Encode(theString).Equals(" ")?"&nbsp;":Html.Encode(theString);
```

Also a non-shorthand-if would be possible but frankly, both options are but ugly.
Isn't there a more readable, compact way of putting that optional space there?

Comment: had to break up the & nbsp; because the SO view renders it as HTML

Comment: Please escape   in the line "...need to be filled with an   I thought..."

Comment: Avoid calling Html.Encode twice for efficiency reasons.

Comment: Not knowing the language, but shouldn't it be like this: encoded = theString.Equals("")?" ":Html.Encode(theString);

Comment: Yes, you are both right, but this was just a way of showing how unreadable such a solution would become.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A space encode in HTML is just a space. nbsp may look like a space, but has a different semantics, "non-breaking" meaning that line breaks are suppressed.

Solution: Whenever I find functionality lacking or with unexpected behavior (e.g. asp:Label and HyperLink don't HTML encode), I write my own utilities class which does as I say ;)

```
public class MyHtml
{
    public static string Encode(string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || s.Trim()=="")
            return "& nbsp;";
        return Html.Encode(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was planning something like this. But before I start implementing my own (and introduce possible change dependancies/bugs) I wanted to be sure there is no better solution.

Comment: I think you should have a special case, like MyHtml.TdEncode which does this. You don't want to add nbsps everyhwere. Also, what is the difference between isNullOrEmpty(s) and s.Trim() == ""? Seems like the trim call is superfluous

Comment: @JuanMendes, the `s.Trim()==""` is necessary because `string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)` will return `false` if `s` contains only spaces. There is the newer `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)` that does handle this condition; but it is not available in .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 5):

It might be simpler to convert the `" "` to `"\xA0"` and then unconditionally `Html.Encode` the result:

```
s = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || s.Trim()=="") ? "\xA0" : s;
Html.Encode(s);
```

Hexadecimal `00A0` identifies the Unicode character for non-breaking space, which is why `&#xA0;` is an equivalent HTML entity to `&nbsp;`.

If you have any control over the database, you could convert the empty or single-space fields to this `"\xA0"` value, which would eliminate the condition altogether.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer to `\xA0`! That came in handy today for something similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find a different way to fill your empty cell. HTML-encoding a space character to itself is perfectly valid. If you need it to be something else you could use URL escaping or roll your own method to generate the content.